# How to get value inside <li> </li> tag in Servlet?

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

```
<ul id ="test">
<li id ="abc">
text1 here
</li>
<li id ="abc1">
text2 here
</li></ul>
```

I am doing with JSP and Servlet and I have some codes like them. And what I want to do with this code is to get the text1, and text2 in Servlet. I called the Servlet in JSP file. So I tried to use request.getParameter("abc") but it resulted in null value. How can I get the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the values of input elements like `<input>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` are sent to the server side upon the submit of a parent [`<form>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html).

The `<li>` is not an input element of any sort. I have no idea what your functional requirement is, so it's very hard to provide a suitable solution,  but you could start looking at `<textarea>`:

```html
<li>
    <textarea name="abc">text1 here</textarea>
</li>
```

Or maybe an `<input type="hidden">`, if you intend to keep it invisible:

```html
<li>
    text1 here
    <input type="hidden" name="abc" value="text1 here" />
</li>
```

Either way, the value will be available as a request parameter with name `abc`.

This has very little to do with JSP/Servlets, it's just very basic HTML knowledge. I'd suggest to go through a bit decent HTML book/tutorial. For example, http://htmldog.com.